# Getting Websphere v7.0 Running with eclipse seems to not see the server start

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-7

So I created a Websphere Application Server in Eclipse and pointed it at my WAS_HOME and the profile I created. Whenever I try to start the server, it starts fine and according to the log I see...

```
[2/22/12 14:16:25:037 EST] 00000000 WsServerImpl  A   WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business
```

However, Eclipse says it is still waiting to start, typically it sticks at 23%. Eventually it times out saying it couldn't start, however, the instance is still up and running fine.

How do I get it to recognize the running instance?

Comment: I fought with Eclipse and IBM WAS some months ago. I lost and i ended using RAD :(

Comment: Had similar fight about a year ago (WebSphere 6.1). Also gave up.

Comment: Add votes then so I can get some rep points to bounty it :-)

Comment: @Jackie how did you solve it? You have enough rep points to bounty it now :)

Comment: Typically this is fixed by double clicking on the server (in eclipse) and setting the timeout to a higher number

Answer (score 1):

Your workspace [folder/name could be the issue.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460336)

or for me it was the WAS installation itself. When I moved it to C:\was8 everything started to work properly. The default puts it into c:\Program Files... and that was hanging at 23%

Answer (score 1):

a. Please use websphere jre to replace sun hotspot vm to launch the eclipse, like below setting in the eclipse.ini

```
-vm
D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/javaw.exe
```

b. Please make sure there is not a specail character (like 23%) in the websphere path or eclipse workpsace.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've got the same problem with Eclipse Luna and Websphere Developer Tools... The problem was the eclipse proxy configuration

Answer (score 0):

Increase the initial and max heap sizes of the VM that is loading Eclipse.