# STS-3.8 WebSphere Application Sever Not Fully Starting

Tags: eclipse, websphere, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-neon

**Issue:** WAS app server v7 does not start in Spring STS. It gets to 100% and just continues to say "launching delegate" and in the system.out file has the standard "open for business" but the server itself in STS never gets to a "Started" status state.

**Platform:** STS-3.8, Always tried on eclipse neon.

**Plugin:** IBM WebSphere Application Server Traditional V7.X Developer Tools for Neon

**WAS Profile:** Created a new profile through the profile management tool for WAS.

**Server Config:**
- Default

Changes Applied:
- Delete contents of /logs, /temp, /tranlog,  /wstemp after my first attempt. Just to clear out the folders. No change in behavior.

[image: Server Status until Timeout]

**Server Start Up Log**

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************

Host Operating System is Windows 7, version 6.1 build 7601 Service Pack 1

Java version = JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 7 amd64-64 jvmwa6460sr10fp1-20120202_101568 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20120202_101568
JIT  - r9_20111107_21307ifx1
GC   - 20120202_AA, Java Compiler = j9jit24, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM

**was.install.root** = C:\IBM\runtimes\base_v7
user.install.root = C:\00_IBM_RAD_PROFILES\stsProfileWAS
Java Home = C:\IBM\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\\IBM\\runtimes\\base_v7\\java\\lib;C:\\IBM\\runtimes\\base_v7\\classes;C:\\IBM\\runtimes\\base_v7\\lib;C:\\IBM\\runtimes\\base_v7\\installedChannels;C:\\IBM\\runtimes\\base_v7\\lib\\ext;C:\\IBM\\runtimes\\base_v7\\web\\help;C:\\IBM\\runtimes\\base_v7\\deploytool\\itp\\plugins\\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\\runtime

Current trace specification = *=info:com.ibm.*=all
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[06/07/16 10:36:29:575 ADT] 00000000 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info:com.ibm.*=all.
[06/07/16 10:36:29:583 ADT] 00000000 WsServerContr 1   Executing executeUtilityOnWindows with args: C:\00_IBM_RAD_PROFILES\stsProfileWAS\config PC123Node20Cell PC123Node20 server1 -script C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\quickServerStart.bat 
[06/07/16 10:36:29:583 ADT] 00000000 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0018I: The trace state has changed. The new trace state is *=info.
[06/07/16 10:36:29:742 ADT] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the stsProfileWAS profile
[06/07/16 10:36:29:744 ADT] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
[06/07/16 10:36:29:827 ADT] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU3300I: Launch script for server created: C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\quickServerStart.bat
```

Comment: I think this isn't primarily related to the spring-tool-suite, but maybe the websphere tooling that you installed in addition to standard STS, so I would recommend to put the websphere tag on the question, too.

Comment: If the `open for e-business` line appears in SystemOut.log, then WAS is running correctly. STS is based on the Eclipse platform, and Eclipse has problems verifying status when connected to WAS. You will find questions on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26988638/6216002) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9401596/6216002).

Comment: @haju - did you get any solution yet?

Comment: @SK - I believe I just started it externally through was commands directly and not from within STS.